# MySQL php find value from column and to column

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL table with

`column-from column-to`

`100 | 120`

with php sql query 
`"WHERE column-from = 100"` or `"WHERE column-to = 120"`

but how between column-from and column-to

example find 105 (100-120) with php mysql ?

Comment: `where column-from>$from AND column-to<$to`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use between :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 105 BETWEEN column-from AND column-to
```

Src : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: this query is for single column where as user want data from two different columns. `WHERE column-from = 100" or "WHERE column-to = 120`

Comment: 100 to 120  so find 105?

Comment: WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
but i want BETWEEN  column-from and column-to find value 105

Comment: SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 105 BETWEEN column-from AND column-to.

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE 105 BETWEEN column-from AND column-to

Answer (score 0):

Simply write query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE column-from >= $from AND column-to <= $to
```

for more [information](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/greater-than-or-equal-operator.php)

Comment: 105 result?? column-from  column-to

Comment: According to your query if you are searching 105 b/w 100 is in the variable `$from` and 120 is in the variable `$to`

Comment: you have to pass value in those variables.

Comment: i can check but i can result

Comment: @A.Sang:  sorry didn't get you.

Comment: i got SELECT * FROM table WHERE 105 BETWEEN column-from AND column-to